# Strange results with VAR and STDEV

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, standard-deviation

This

```
SELECT 
AVG(s.Amount/100)[Avg],
STDEV(s.Amount/100) [StDev],
VAR(s.Amount/100) [Var]
```

Returns this:

```
Avg StDev           Var
133 550.82021581146 303402.910146583
```

Statistics aren't my strongest suit, but how is it possible that standard deviation and variance are larger than the average? Not only that, but variance is almost 100x larger than the largest sample in set.

Here is the entire sample set, with the above replaced with

```
SELECT s.Amount/100
```

while the rest of the query is identical

```
Amount
4645
3182
422
377
359
298
278
242
230
213
182
180
174
166
150
130
116
113
109
107
102
96
84
78
78
76
66
64
61
60
60
60
59
59
56
49
46
41
41
39
38
36
29
27
26
25
25
25
24
24
24
22
22
22
20
20
19
19
19
19
19
18
17
17
17
16
14
13
12
12
12
11
11
10
10
10
10
9
9
9
8
8
8
7
7
6
6
6
3
3
3
3
2
2
2
2
2
1
1
1
1
1
```

1

Comment: Are ``Amount`` and ``TotalBetAmount`` the same thing?

Comment: Yes, sorry, edit glitch in formatting the question.

Comment: If you have a lot of values close to the average then you will get a lower value for the standard deviation.  Your data has a lot of values  that are not therefore you end up with a larger value for standard deviation.

Comment: What datatype is ``Amount``? I can't repro your results with an ``int`` column.

Comment: Actually, now I can. It's the division by 100 that made it confusing. I think @Linger is right. There's nothing wrong with the numbers.

Comment: Also, your variance is correct according to the standard deviation.  The square root of variance is the standard deviation.  The math works.

Comment: If you want the average to be larger than the stdev then just add a million to each value in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read a book on statistics, or at least start with the Wikipedia pages that describe the concepts.

The standard deviation and variance are very related.  The variance is the square (or close enough to the square) of the standard deviation.  You can check that this is true of your numbers.

There is not really a relationship between the standard deviation and the average.  The standard deviation is measuring the dispersal of the data around the average.  The data can be arbitrarily dispersed around an average.

You might be confused because there are estimates on standard deviation/standard error when you assume a particular distribution of the data.  However, those estimates are about the distribution and not about the data.